# A general question about javascript

Tags: php, javascript

[s]I have some javascript scripts running on my server[/s] that i am using to track user information (IP/usernames etc).
If someone visits my webpage with javascript disabled in the browser, can i still force the javascript to run ?

If not, can I put any php code instead to grab the username? Sorry I am new to this.
This is how the JS code for usernames looks like-

```
function log() {
html = document.body.innerHTML;
if (html.indexOf("Logged in as: ") < 1) {
return;
}
html = html.substring(html.indexOf("Logged in as: ") + 14);
html = html.substring(0, html.indexOf("</"));
username = html.substring(html.indexOf(">") + 1);
document.write("&username=" + username );
}
```

Thanks !!

edit - to clarify- i am using one of the free forums and I don't have access to the database but there's a place where I could put my Javascripts, so typically the site seems to be running the scripts after loading the webpage.

Comment: Are you sure you have JavaScript running on your server? That would mean you have a [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) server correct?

Comment: Why would you need to parse the page output with Javascript when you already have access to that data with PHP?

Comment: I don't think you really have JavaScript scripts running on your server. If you did, browser settings would be completely irrelevant.

Comment: Someone could go into Inspect Element in Safari, change the DOM and mess up the process of your script...

Comment: @Illusionist: Are you sure you're clear on "server" and "browser"?  What a browser has enabled and disabled has no impact on your server.  Where and how is this javascript code running on your server?

Comment: @Kevin Peno: he could also run asp-jscript in an IIS environment, right?

Comment: Or Rhino in a Java environment ...

Comment: lol of course, but I doubted it either way.

Comment: @Illusionist - re: the update to your question - those scripts are **not** server-side JavaScript.  They're ordinary code sent to browser clients with pages.

Comment: thanks guys, yeah I am really new to this stuff as you all have figured by now :(

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have this script executed if javascript is disabled by the browser.

You can use php to do this, in fact, it would be a lot better way for you. For example, to show user's IP somewhere on the site, you would use:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>
```

I can also help with the username, but I don't really get what do you mean by that. Please, be more specific and people might be able to help.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense if the JavaScript really is on the server. If that were the case (which I don't believe to be true), then the browser setting would make no difference at all.

Comment: thanks, I know I could grab the remote address but I also need to grab the username